# ASP.NET Core 3 - Is there a way to add Module section to produced Web Config File

Tags: iis, web-config, asp.net-core-webapi

Like said in the title i'm publishing an ASP.NET Core 3 API to IIS. When i publish that API the system create a web config file in the deploy directory containing that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\xxxxx.Api.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: daddb75b-3c54-4970-8945-8404ade81fbc-->
```

Everything is ok but what's i want to do is to add the three lines below in the **System.webServer** section in order to cover the issue described in this link : https://fantinel.dev/net-core-api-method-not-allowed-on-put-and-delete-requests/
Extract for explanations :

> What happens is that, when published, .NET Core enables the
>   WebDAVModule, which disables PUT and DELETE requests by default.

So to get PUT and DELETE verbs we have to disable this WebDAVModule with this lines :

```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
```

Is there a way to automatize the include of this lines to the produced/published web.config ? In the VS solution i don't see any Web.Config file or option to drive the output of deploy.

Thanks you all for your advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out that when you add a `web.config` file yourself, the publishing wizard combines the normally generated web.config with the file you define yourself. Eg:

No web.config ==> Produces following web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MintPlayer.Web.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 7b031640-46da-4eac-b60c-740bd3659fce-->
```

Following web.config in the root of your ASP.NET Core project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Produces following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MintPlayer.Web.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

So it seems that the ASP.NET Core deployment is combining both xml's. I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you very much for your help that's **exactly** what i needed. I'm so sorry for this late comment (in fact, i haven't deployed anything since décember, shame on me ;-) ....) but till just now i'm using your solution that seems to work really well. 
(and I'm even a little ashamed of not having tried the trick myself. Very good intuition that you had !)